# Query MySql in PHP with Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

What is difference between

In application 1 / 2:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('tu');

                $transUnits = $qb->select('tu, te')
                    ->leftJoin('tu.translations', 'te')
                    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('tu.id', $ids))
                    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('te.locale', $locales))
                    ->orderBy(sprintf('tu.%s', $sortColumn), $order)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getArrayResult();

and

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('tu');

                $transUnits = $qb->select('tu, te')
                    ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Translation', 'te')
                    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('tu.id', $ids))
                    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('te.locale', $locales))
                    ->orderBy(sprintf('tu.%s', $sortColumn), $order)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getArrayResult();
```

The functions are called with the exact same parameters.

In the second case I replace 'tu.translations' with 'AppBundle:Translation' because do not recognize 'translations' where translations is define:

```
<one-to-many field="translations" target-entity="TranslationBundle\Entity\Translation" mapped-by="transUnit">
            <cascade>
                <cascade-all/>
            </cascade>
</one-to-many>
```

In the first case result is: array(13) { ... } and this is the correct format result; in the second case wrong format result is: array(70) { ... }

Comment: call `->getDQL` on each query (after `->getQuery()`) and you will see.

Comment: I add annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I add in entity class:

```
/**
     * @var \Translation
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Translation", mappedBy="transUnit")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="trans_unit_id")
     * })
     */
    protected $translations;
```

and

```
/**
     * @var \TransUnit
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TransUnit", inversedBy="translations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="trans_unit_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    protected $transUnit;
```

And work. :)